# Flink 1.7.1 fails to authenticate s3a with core-site.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, bigdata, apache-flink

Using Flink 1.7.1 building it for a single job cluster on kubernetes flink fails to load core-site xml despite being on the classpath, resulting in disregarding of the configuration, however, if i put ENV variables AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID it works by finding it, but if i depend on core-site.xml it never works without the env variables.

I am currently copying the core-site.xml as it is shown in the Dockerfile and as the documentation says putting HADOOP_CONF_DIR as env variable pointing to it. Still it does not load it, resulting in NoCredentialsProvider.

Exception is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by 
BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: 
Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

Classpath loaded by job manager/task manager

```
-  Classpath: 


/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.489.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.489.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/flink-python_2.12-1.7.1.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.1.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.7.1.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/httpclient-4.5.6.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/httpcore-4.4.11.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/job.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/joda-time-2.10.1.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar
:/opt/flink-1.7.1/lib/flink-dist_2.12-1.7.1.jar
:
:/hadoop/conf:
```

Dockerfile to build the docker image:

```
################################################################################
#  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
#  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
#  distributed with this work for additional information
#  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
#  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
#  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
#  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
################################################################################

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Install requirements
# Modification to original Dockerfile to support rocksdb
# RUN apk add --no-cache bash snappy
# This is a fix for RocksDB compatibility


# Flink environment variables
ENV FLINK_INSTALL_PATH=/opt
ENV FLINK_HOME $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH/flink
ENV FLINK_LIB_DIR $FLINK_HOME/lib
ENV PATH $PATH:$FLINK_HOME/bin
ENV FLINK_CONF $FLINK_HOME/conf
ENV FLINK_OPT $FLINK_HOME/opt
ENV FLINK_HADOOP_CONF /hadoop/conf

# flink-dist can point to a directory or a tarball on the local system
ARG flink_dist=NOT_SET
ARG job_jar=NOT_SET

# Install build dependencies and flink
ADD $flink_dist $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH
ADD $job_jar $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH/job.jar

RUN set -x && \
  ln -s $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH/flink-* $FLINK_HOME && \
  ln -s $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH/job.jar $FLINK_LIB_DIR && \
  addgroup -S flink && adduser -D -S -H -G flink -h $FLINK_HOME flink && \
  chown -R flink:flink $FLINK_INSTALL_PATH/flink-* && \
  chown -h flink:flink $FLINK_HOME

# Modification to original Dockerfile
RUN apk add --no-cache bash libc6-compat snappy 'su-exec>=0.2'

COPY core-site.xml $FLINK_HADOOP_CONF/core-site.xml
ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$FLINK_HADOOP_CONF

RUN echo "fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: $FLINK_HADOOP_CONF" >> $FLINK_CONF/flink-conf.yaml

RUN echo "akka.ask.timeout: 30 min" >> $FLINK_CONF/flink-conf.yaml

RUN echo "akka.client.timeout: 30 min" >> $FLINK_CONF/flink-conf.yaml
RUN echo "web.timeout: 180000" >> $FLINK_CONF/flink-conf.yaml

RUN mv $FLINK_OPT/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.1.jar $FLINK_LIB_DIR

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.8.0/hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.6/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
#Transitive Dependency of aws-java-sdk-s3
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.489.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.489/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.489.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.489.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/1.11.489/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.489.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.8/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/joda-time-2.10.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.1/joda-time-2.10.1.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/httpcore-4.4.11.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.11/httpcore-4.4.11.jar
RUN wget -O $FLINK_LIB_DIR/httpclient-4.5.6.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar
#Modification to original Dockerfile

USER flink
EXPOSE 8081 6123
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Comma separated list of local directories used to buffer
         large results prior to transmitting them to S3. -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <description>AWS access key ID.
            Omit for IAM role-based or provider-based authentication.</description>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <description>AWS secret key.
            Omit for IAM role-based or provider-based authentication.</description>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>


    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider</value>
    </property>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this has been resolved, if you have the shaded hadoop on the classpath (moving it from /opt to /lib) you need to specify your keys in the flink-conf, however now i am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider 
constructor exception.  A class specified in fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider must provide a public constructor accepting URI and Configuration, or a public factory method named getInstance that accepts no arguments, or a public default constructor.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like Flink is trying to load the standard credential provider (the one that takes those fs.s3a keys) and failing as it can't find or instantiate it. Possibly classpath problems, otherwise maybe the whole shading is causing confusion.

Comment: Honestly, i couldn't make it locate core-site.xml. Tried almost everything, i was using the shaded hadoop provided by /opt folder, just moved it to lib, still to no avail.
I guess there is some default behaviour in the shaded hadoop that ignores the provided core-site.xml. Someone with more internal code knowledge needs to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Adding hadoop-common with the appropriate version to the Dockerfile helped.